# jQuery blur issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with my form code.

Here it is on codepen: http://codepen.io/Dzongkha/pen/NbdadP

The issue is with this piece of code:

```
jQuery('.form-container input, .form-container textarea').each(function() {
    var labelLeft, labelTop;

    labelTop = jQuery(this).css('padding-top');
    labelLeft = jQuery(this).css('padding-left');

    jQuery(this).next('label').css({
      'top': labelTop,
      'left': labelLeft,
    });

    jQuery(this).on('focus', function() {
      jQuery(this).next('label').attr({
        'style': '',
      });

      var leftProperty, topProperty,inputWidth;
      leftProperty = jQuery(this).next('label').css('left');
      inputWidth = jQuery(this).css('width');
      topProperty = jQuery(this).next('label').css('top');

      if(leftProperty == inputWidth) {
        jQuery(this).next('label').css({
          'left': labelLeft,
        });
      };

      if(topProperty == '0px') {
        jQuery(this).next('label').css({
          'top': labelTop,
        });
      };
    });

    jQuery(this).on('blur', function() {
      if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
        jQuery(this).next('label').css({
          'top': labelTop,
          'left': labelLeft,
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

So if I focus and blur just on codepen page - everything is ok and looks like that: [proper variant](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz8lGkS7BckbNFllTzZiVFIwY00).

But if I blur by opening new tab or another program, or with console and then trying to focus on input or textarea, there is such an issue: [issue variant](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz8lGkS7BckbMExTRU1mak1rc2s).

I don't know, why, but in this case this part of code:

```
          jQuery(this).next('label').attr({
            'style': '',
          });
```

doesn't work for some reason.

What I've already tried:

1)

```
jQuery(this).next('label').css({
        'top': '',
        'left': ''
      });
```

2)

```
jQuery(this).next('label').removeAttr('style');
```

But in both cases there was that issue.

Hope that there is a way to resolve my problem =(

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try find('label') instead of next('label')

Comment: check `label ` tag in your html

Comment: @karthick I've tried, but it doesn't help at all

Comment: @prasad yes, there is no <label> in html because in my js code piece of it grab placeholders and make labels from them. Check your console please.

Comment: @prasad ok, I've tried but it doesn't help (and, sorry, I can't understand, why it could be helpful in my problem)

Comment: I've told that I've tried after you've written it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Why do you need javascript? You can do all of this with css only... let me try it for you

Comment: @SandrinaPereira yes, I need JS, cause it's part of bigger project. And I need to solve this problem with jQuery/JS

Comment: My question is if you need js for this particular input, why overcomplicating the situation when with css is faster and smaller

Comment: @SandrinaPereira Could you please explan what do you mean about overcomplicating?

Answer (score 1):

You code is a little confuse, I think you have to much code to do something simple. You have some js code that is overlapping and that's why your bug.

You are having that bug with devtools (console) because you are forcing a status, and when that happens the js doesn't recognize the modification, that's why the style padding doesn't change.

I still don't understand why you have such big js code for something simple, I recommend you to refactor the code with css only and it solves the problem. Otherwise I think I can't help you.

My solution is not the best but it works, by adding `!important` to top and left properties on css.

```
#example-3.form-container input:focus + label,
#example-3.form-container input.active + label,
#example-3.form-container textarea:focus + label,
#example-3.form-container textarea.active + label {
  top: 1px !important;
  left: 1px !important;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f04c1e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Also where you have jQuery on your code, you can replace it by only the $ dollar sign `$`.

http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/qqRVNw

Comment: Look. I've tried to explain that this js is a part of much bigger project. I have nearly 20-25 different forms with different effects and I need to solve this exact task to add some more functionality for them all (not only for this form). This task is just a step to new things and I can't just replace it with CSS property with important.

I just need to fix this exact bug, not change CSS file for this effect.

Comment: I get it. You are having that bug with console, because you are forcing a status, and when that happens the js doesn't recognize the modification, that's why the style padding doesn't change. I still don't understand why you have such big js code for something simple, I recommend you to refactor the code with css only and it solves the problem. Otherwise I think I can't help you.